Remove empty space at the end of line chart in Excel
How do I remove the extra space at the end of the line chart with the picture below. The NAs will be changed to actual numbers every week (So next column E will be changed to actual numbers), so I can't just delete the NAs. I need the chart to just not graph them when they are NA, but when changed to an actual number add them.

All of the solutions I have tried online just mess with how the NAs are plotted and none of them actually removed them while keeping the plot dynamic.

Use dynamic range names to cover only the range that has data, and plug the dynamic range name into the chart.

I created two range names with the following formulas:
cRangeA =Sheet2!$B$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$G$1,COUNT(Sheet2!$B$1:$G$1))
cRangeB =OFFSET(cRangeA,1,0)
Then edit the chart series and use the range name as the series value.
You can use any formula in the range name that delivers the correct range. In this case, for Series A I start in B2 and count how many columns in the range B2 to G2 have numbers in them. For Series B I use the same data shape, but one row below.

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.
